# Combining multiple diacritics from unicode input

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode

I have trouble combining multiple diacritics in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}  

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

Ā́ Łōgī́ zǭ́ze

\end{document}
```

The acute accents should always show up above everything else, but they are printed over the other diacritics. 
This is in xelatex:

[image]

This is an even worse output in lualatex:

[image]

It should be:

[image]

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Which language is this?

Comment: @Mico This is in [Kaska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaska_language) (British Columbia).

Comment: It depends on the font. Arial e.g. is perfect, cambria ok with xelatex but not so good with lualatex, latin modern and also the tex gyre fonts are bad (and are missing the ogonek).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmm, I see.  I'm trying with some of my system fonts and most work quite well.  Oh fonts ...  So there is no way to make this "any font safe"?

Comment: I don't think so. You could probably define some command to get better output but for automatical placement the font must imho have gpos lookups: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gpos (Arial has them).

Answer (score 4):

With the Combining Diacritical Marks unicode  block, you can build up the sequence of marks by hand, so to speak. They will follow the order you specify.

[image: sequence order]

And they will pile up (and under) for as many as you specify.

[image: piling up and under]

So you can create your own combinations if you need to.

Manually adding marks:

first line is ordinary text pasted in from the MWE; second line is manually built-up marks.

[image: manually added accents]

It becomes a case of finding the right mark.

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\cdmacute{\symbol{"0301}}
\newcommand\cdmmacron{\symbol{"0304}}
\newcommand\cdmhook{\symbol{"0309}}
\newcommand\cdmring{\symbol{"030A}}
\newcommand\cdmdoublea{\symbol{"030B}}
\newcommand\cdmhacek{\symbol{"030C}}
\newcommand\cdmsolidus{\symbol{"0337}}
\newcommand\cdmseagull{\symbol{"033C}}
\newcommand\cdmsquare{\symbol{"033B}}
\newcommand\cdmbridge{\symbol{"033A}}
\newcommand\cdmbreve{\symbol{"032E}}
\newcommand\cdmogonek{\symbol{"0328}}

\begin{document}\
\noindent Ā́ Łōgī́ zǭ́ze 

A\cdmmacron\cdmacute\ L\cdmsolidus o\cdmmacron gi\cdmmacron\cdmacute\  zo\cdmmacron\cdmacute\cdmogonek ze

A\cdmacute\cdmmacron A\cdmmacron\cdmacute

o\symbol{"0302}\symbol{"032B}

\vspace{12pt}
A\cdmhook\cdmring\cdmdoublea\cdmhacek\cdmacute\cdmseagull\cdmsquare\cdmbridge\cdmbreve
\vspace{12pt}

A\cdmsolidus B\cdmsolidus C\cdmsolidus

 L\cdmsolidus

\end{document}
```

And with the `ucharclasses` package, the accents (or the letters) can be brought in from another font, if desired.